# Cannot connect to AWS RDS SQL Server instance from SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS SQL Server instance (Express edition). Initially, I created a t2.medium instance. I was able to connect to it from my SQL Server 2012 Management Studio without any problems.

But now I modified my RDS instance from t2.medium to t2.micro (free trial version) by using the Modify Instance option. The modification was done successfully. No other changes were done, but now I am unable to access the instance through the SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. The server name, port, and credentials are all same as before. For testing purposes, the VPC security group has the incoming rule set to allow "All Traffic at all times". But somehow the following error appears whenever I try to connect.

> "Cannot connect to ...
>
> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

Kindly help me, as I am unable to easily access my database. If there is any other way to access the database easily do let me know.